# Can "data at rest" in the Realm Mobile Platform be encrypted?

Tags: realm

Realm supports encrypting the database file on disk with AES-256+SHA2 by supplying a 64-byte encryption key when creating a Realm.

Since the **Realm Mobile Platform** is self hosted (inhouse or via cloud) - does that effectively also mean that this same database file encryption is available ? I'm assuming 'yes' but since I was always taught "never assume" I wanted to ask the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the same encryption is also available for synched Realms. However, note that if you supply an encryption key to the `SyncConfiguration` only the local file is encrypted, not the file on the server or other devices. You would need to supply the encryption on each of these as well.

This also means that it is possible for one device to encrypt the data and send them to a device that saves them unencrypted.

On the wire we use TLS if you enabled it (which you should).