# Is end-to-end encryption possible with Realm Mobile Platform?

Tags: encryption, realm, realm-mobile-platform

On the client device, a synced Realm can be setup with an encryption key that's unique to the user and stored on the device keychain, so data is stored encrypted on the client. 
(related question: [Can "data at rest" in the Realm Mobile Platform be encrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253594/can-data-at-rest-in-the-realm-mobile-platform-be-encrypted))

Realm Object Server and the clients can communicate via TLS, so data is encrypted in transit.

But the Realm Object Server does not appear to store data using encryption, since an admin user is able to access all the database contents via Realm Browser (https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#data-browser).

Is it possible to setup Realm Mobile Platform so user data is encrypted end-to-end, such as no one but the user (not even server admins) have access to the decryption key?

Comment: There's a difference between end-to-end encryption and encryption at rest. Think about your Whatsapp chats: There's e2e encryption and still both parts on the chat are able to see the contents. If you don't want the server admins to have access to you data, then the data should be encrypted on the device before even leaving it. That way the encryption key will remain on the device and the data will be unusable on the server.

Comment: So it seems the only way to achieve this is to manually encrypt all the fields in my Realm models, using a key stored on the device keychain? But this would break the "sync" feature of Realm Mobile Platform unless I can also sync that encryption key between the user's devices (using a 3rd party secured sync mechanism like iCloud Keychain). Perhaps feasible but not very practical.

Comment: It depends on the type of data you're storing. If you're doing a chat between users then the e2e encryption makes sense. In any other case I think your offer could be encrypt data using a password on the device and when required on another device the same password will be required in order to decrypt it. I don't know if this is scalable. Anyway this is the way encrypted notes work on Evernote time ago (I'm not an Evernote user anymore.) Check your options. You'll have to choose.

Comment: Thanks. The data is similar to notes, and I wanted to have "seamless" (no login or passwords) sync between multiple devices for the same user, though p2p sharing may be added later. 
I just didn't want the burden/responsibility of having access to the users' private data. 
Since it's an iOS-only app, I considered CloudKit as the backend to avoid this issue, but haven't found good solutions that do sync between CloudKit and Realm, and rolling my own sync system is out of scope for now. So I was hoping to use a drop-in system like RMP in a way that also absolves me from privacy concerns.

Comment: Update: there are no issues around conflict resolution; we're working on the integration. Ping me if you'd like to sign up for an early preview. David/ZeroKit team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way we handle conflict resolution, we currently are unable to provide end-to-end encryption, as you correctly deduced. Let's go a tiny bit into detail with regards to the conflict resolution.

In order to handle conflicts the way we do, we use something called [operational transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation). This means that instead of sending the data over directly, the client tells the server the intent of the change, rather than the result. For example, when two users edit a text field, we would tell the server `insert(data='new text', offset=0)` because the first user prepended data at the beginning of the text field, and `insert(data='some more stuff', offset=10)` because the second user added data in the middle of the field. These two separate operations allow the server to uniquely resolve what happened, and have conflictless resolution of the two writes.

This also means that if we encrypt everything, the server would be unable to handle this conflict resolution.

This being said, that's for the current version. We do have a number of thoughts on how we could handle this in the future, while providing (some degree) of encryption. Mainly this would mean more work on the client, and maybe find a new algorithm that would allow us to tell the client the intent, and let the client figure out how to merge everything. This is a quadratic problem, though, so we're reticent to putting too much work on the client side, as it could really drain the battery.

That might be acceptable for some users, which is why we're looking into it. Basically, there will be a trade-off. As the old adage goes: fast, secure, convenient: pick two. We just have to figure out how to handle this properly.

Answer (score 1):

I just opened a feature request around possibly using Tresorit's ZeroKit to solve the end-to-end encryption question posed.  Sounds like the conflict resolution implementation will still cause an issue though, but maybe there is a different conflict resolution level that can be applied for those that don't need the realtime dynamic editing of individual data fields (like patient health data, where only a single clinician ever really edits a record at any given time).

https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/96